# Use of history.back in animated .scrollleft

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slider, jquery-animate

I am struggeling with a back button on my horizontal webpage. The way I use the backbutton at the moment is an onclick="history.go(-1). The problem is that doesn't let me use the sliding that takes place at all other buttons. The rest of the website works fine, This is the only bug that I have to get under control. You can take a look at the website here: www.gerardsteurvormgeving.nl

Part of the code I use ( a little of the html with the backbutton that is called "terug" onclick="history.go(-1) and the javascript you'll find under this text. I hope someone can help me with this!!!! Thanks a million in advance!!

All the best,

Gerard

```
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
$('.blue').bind('click', function (event) {
history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr("href"));

var $anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left - ($(window).width() - $($anchor.attr('href')).width()) / 2
}, 2500);


event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="blue" href="#section4" title="home" style="position: absolute; left: 94.99%; top: 7.22%; width: 0.31%; height: 3.47%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a class="blue" href="#section2" title="contact" style="position: absolute; left: 94.92%; top: 13.06%; width: 0.46%; height: 3.33%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a class="blue" title="terug" onclick="history.go(-1)" style="position: absolute; left: 94.96%; top: 27.64%; width: 0.38%; height: 3.75%; z-index: 2;">        </a>
<a class="blue" href="#section1" title="download pagina" style="position: absolute; left: 98.11%; top: 71.25%; width: 0.93%; height: 9.86%; z-index: 2;"></a>  

<a href="subpages/7 trainingen en de teamdag/sociale vaardigheden.html" title="de keuze re-integratie trainingen - sociale vaardigheden" style="position: absolute; left: 96.46%; top: 22.22%; width: 1.88%; height: 6.53%; z-index: 2;"></a>

<a href="subpages/7 trainingen en de teamdag/beroepsorientatie.html" title="de keuze re-integratie trainingen - beroepsorientatie" style="position: absolute; left: 96.6%; top: 41.67%; width: 1.67%; height: 6.53%; z-index: 2;"></a>

<a href="subpages/7 trainingen en de teamdag/solliciteren.html" title="de keuze re-integratie trainingen - sollicitatie trainingen" style="position: absolute; left: 96.76%; top: 57.92%; width: 1.26%; height: 9.86%; z-index: 2;"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery, why not simply add a history manager like jQuery.BBQ or hashchange or history.js ?

That way, the back button will work just as you are expecting it to. Other techniques like the one you are using can have a workaround as well, but it's still better if you use history management libraries like the one mentioned above.

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/) using HTML5:

*This does not have the sliding effect you wanted, but will give you an idea* :)

**HTML Code**

```
<h1>Navigation Without Refresh <span></span></h1>
<h2>Current Page: <span>/</span></h2>
<ul id="menu-nav">
    <li><a href="/page-1/" title="Pagina 1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page-2/" title="Pagina 2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page-3/" title="Pagina 3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var setCurrentPage = function(url) {
    $('h2 span').html(url || "/");
    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + url + "']").fadeTo(500, 0.3);
};

$('#menu-nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
    targetTitle = $(this).attr('title');

    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").fadeTo(500, 1.0);

    window.history.pushState({url: "" + targetUrl + ""}, targetTitle, targetUrl);
    setCurrentPage(targetUrl);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $("#menu-nav a").fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    setCurrentPage(e.state ? e.state.url : null);
};
```

Comment: Hi mrid, first of all thanks for your answer!! I tried to use history.js for my back button, and looked up a lot of documentation of how to implement the back button. I tried to make it slide back as well, but I just couldn't get the right code! Could you help me push me in the right direction? I don't know how to make the html <a tag correspond right with the javascript so it still slides and goes back.. Thanks a million in advance!!!